# momentjs date collation from a json table

Tags: date, momentjs

### Background

- momentjs 2.8.3
- angularjs
- collating dates in a date table

### Problem

Trevor wishes to get the global timespan of dates in a date table, where each record contains a start date and an end date.

#### Goal

- The goal is to get a global timespan, such that the earliest part of the timespan reflects the earliest date in any row the table, and the latest part of the timespan reflects the latest date in any row the table.
- Trevor does not know in advance how the dates are arranged in the table, other than they are all formatted as 'YYYY-MM-DD'
- Trevor is sold on momentjs as the most effective js library for handling this kind of problem, but he is open to using any others.

#### Details

The data is all encoded in JSON and structured as below.

````
```
dataroot {
  "datedemo_data_table": [
    {
      "datebeg": "2014-01-15",
      "dateend": "2014-02-15"
    },
    {
      "datebeg": "2014-03-15",
      "dateend": "2015-01-01"
    },
    {
      "datebeg": "2015-06-15",
      "dateend": "2015-07-20"
    },
    {
      "datebeg": "2012-08-15",
      "dateend": "2013-08-15"
    },
    {
      "datebeg": "2013-01-15",
      "dateend": "2013-01-16"
    }
  ],
  "datedemosummary_data_dict": {
    "x": "x",
    "ds_soonst_date": "",
    "ds_latest_date": ""
  }
}
```
````

The goal is to populate the `ds_soonst_date` and `ds_latest_date` with the correct date values.

### Questions

- Is momentjs the best library for a task such as this?
- Are there any performance implications for large data tables (over 10k records)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need moment (or any library) for this.  Since the values are in YYYY-MM-DD format, they are sortable as strings.  Simple array/object manipulation will work.

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"datedemo_data_table":[{"datebeg":"2014-01-15","dateend":"2014-02-15"},{"datebeg":"2014-03-15","dateend":"2015-01-01"},{"datebeg":"2015-06-15","dateend":"2015-07-20"},{"datebeg":"2012-08-15","dateend":"2013-08-15"},{"datebeg":"2013-01-15","dateend":"2013-01-16"}],"datedemosummary_data_dict":{"x":"x","ds_soonst_date":"","ds_latest_date":""}}');

var firstBegDate = data.datedemo_data_table
                       .map(function(x){return x.datebeg;})
                       .sort().shift();

var lastEndDate = data.datedemo_data_table
                       .map(function(x){return x.dateend;})
                       .sort().pop();
```

As far as performance goes - if you have 10k items in a single JSON, that's probably an issue right there.  You will always have O(n) performance with any approach unless you use an *index* to reduce the data to start with.

Comment: **// You actually don't need moment (or any library) for this //** True, but momentjs is being used to get the dates into iso8601 format to begin with, as the users are mostly USA-centric and they tend to enter dates in MM/DD/YY or MM/DD/YYYY format. momentjs is being used to normalize the routinely irregular date input. Also this post was mostly for self-answering. Thanks for the valid point though.

Comment: Be careful though.  A *whole date* has a different meaning than that same date at midnight.  There are some days that don't *have* a local midnight.  For example, in São Paulo, Brazil, 2014-10-19 exists, but 2014-10-19T00:00:00 does not!  Because DST transitions right at midnight there, the clock jumps from 23:59:59.999 to 01:00:00.000 on that day.  In some browsers, if you pass `new Date(2014,9,19)`, you'll get 2014-10-19T01:00:00, but in other browsers, you'll get 2014-10-18T23:00:00!  Moment is not immune from this problem.  Thus don't assign a date a time unless you need to.

Comment: Keep in mind that both the JavaScript `Date` object and a `moment` both represent a point in time.  (IMHO, `Date` should have been called `DateTime`)

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

momentjs is an excellent choice as it is a well-documented and feature-full library.

The performance question is not addressed here, perhaps someone else can chime in on that.

Nevertheless with a small table of a few values, you can get a quick result by doing a collation of the dates into a single javascript array, and then extracting the max and min using the relevant functions from momentjs.

This can be done easily with the following:

### Solution

```
            var fmt = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                ,ddtemp =  $scope.dataroot.datedemosummary_data_dict
                ,aatemp_dates =  []
                ;

            $scope.dataroot.datedemo_data_table.forEach(function(currow, ixx, arr) {
              aatemp_dates.push(moment(currow.datebeg,fmt));
              aatemp_dates.push(moment(currow.dateend,fmt));
            },ddtemp);

            ddtemp.ds_soonst_date = (moment.min(aatemp_dates).format(fmt));
            ddtemp.ds_latest_date = (moment.max(aatemp_dates).format(fmt));
```

### Result

```
          dataroot {
            "datedemo_data_table": [
              {
                "datebeg": "2014-01-15",
                "dateend": "2014-02-15"
              },
              {
                "datebeg": "2014-03-15",
                "dateend": "2015-01-01"
              },
              {
                "datebeg": "2015-06-15",
                "dateend": "2015-07-20"
              },
              {
                "datebeg": "2012-08-15",
                "dateend": "2013-08-15"
              },
              {
                "datebeg": "2013-01-15",
                "dateend": "2013-01-16"
              }
            ],
            "datedemosummary_data_dict": {
              "x": "x",
              "ds_soonst_date": "2012-08-15",
              "ds_latest_date": "2015-07-20"
            }
          }
```

### See also

- momentjs #min
- momentjs #max
- momentjs range addon library by gf3 https://github.com/gf3/moment-range